# How to replace strapis default wysiwyg editor to CKEditor

Tags: node.js, ckeditor, strapi

I am trying to use CKEditor for strapi project, but failing to integrate.

What I did so far:

- `strapi new cms --quickstart` It is starting me new cms application.
- `npm install ckeditor`
- Edit the code located at `./plugins/content-manager/admin/src/component/Edit/index.js` to CKEditor implementation
- `npm run build` to see my changes, tried `npm run setup` too

But here I'm getting error `webpackJsonp is not defined`

I'm not providing the code how I modified, because, `build` command is not reaching till there.

I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the default WYSIWYG in Strapi you will need to

1. Fork the repository check out [the CONTRIBUTING GUIDE](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)
2. Once you have the development setup you can directly modify the code in `packages/strapi-plugin-content-manager/admin/src/components/WYSIWYGWithErrors` and its related children. Install the dependency in `strapi-admin`
3. Uninstall the content manager plugin (again make sure you are running the latest version of Strapi
4. Copy the `strapi-plugin-content-manager` package inside your app's plugin folder (rename it `content-manager`)
5. Copy the following [file](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-admin/admin/src/plugins.js) in `my-app/admin/src/plugins.js` and change the paths of the plugins so it matches your new one
6. run yarn develop

Comment: Thank you @soupette for answering, I will let you know if it works

Comment: @Mukhammadsher I have published an article on how to do it https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi?redirectPage=1

Comment: Hey @soupette, did you remove the last part of the article? In point three, the customizations in WysiwygWithErrors and CKEditor index.js is missing, i guess..